# AWS S3 bucket boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have written following code to create a AWS S3 bucket using boto:-

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection()

bucket = conn.create_bucket('mybucket1')
```

But When I ran this code I am getting following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prob1.py", line 3, in <module>
    bucket = conn.create_bucket('mybucket1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 619, in create_bucket
    data=data)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 671, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 913, in _mexe
    self.is_secure)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 705, in get_http_connection
    return self.new_http_connection(host, port, is_secure)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 747, in new_http_connection
    connection = self.proxy_ssl(host, is_secure and 443 or 80)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 792, in proxy_ssl
    int(self.proxy_port)), timeout)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err

socket.timeout: timed out
```

I am not using any proxy server.
Help me to debug this code.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine.

The error is a timeout, which suggests a networking issue, such as a port being blocked by corporate IT.

Try it from another network (eg from home) and you'll find that it will work correctly. It is then a matter of tracking down whoever runs your network to figure out what is blocking your connection.

Alternatively, create an Amazon EC2 instance, connect to it (if possible), and run your code from there.

Comment: I have already try over two network still I am getting same error and Thanks for help.